# UI-Select and AngularJS with a big list of items

Tags: angularjs

I'm using UI-Select with AngularJS to show an Autocomplete/Dropdown with a big list of items (~5k). Unfortunately UI-Select is having big performance Issues with this amount of items (~3sec to open the dropdown). I've read about several possibilities to boost the performance like setting a minimum input length but unfortunately they are not an option for me.

What I've found out is, that the amount of watchers is exploding when the dropdown is beeing opened. I've tried to remove the 2-way data binding but then the filter functionality is not working anymore.

How can I get UI-Select working with an acceptable performance but still having the possibility to filter items by the users input? I am also free to suggestions of other directives that are doing something similiar as UI-Select but are doing better in terms of performance.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it fit to the guidelines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You can use other Bootstrap UI components for displaying the data like UI-Select,*

but if you want to make it run faster, you need to minimise the number of watchers. For that you need to remove two-way data-binding (`ng-model="data"` or `{{data}}`) and switch to one-way data-binding (`ng-bind="data"` or `{{::data}}`).

This will prevent you from using a filter (to search / select the data). So a workaround is to use `ng-show` / `ng-if` to show the relevant data. Here is an example

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name:"adam"},
    {name:"kevin"},
    {name:"billy"},
    {name:"alice"},
    {name:"bob"}
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <input ng-model="query" />
  <h3>Two-way data-binding <small>(slow)</small></h3>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:query">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
  <hr>
  <h3>One-way data-binding <small>(fast)</small></h3>
  <li ng-repeat="item in ::items" ng-show="([item.name] | filter:query).length">
    {{::item.name}}
  </li>

</div>
```

Here is an example of what it can look like by using Dropdown with a template:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [{
      name: "adam"
    },
    {
      name: "kevin"
    },
    {
      name: "billy"
    },
    {
      name: "alice"
    },
    {
      name: "bob"
    }
  ];
  $scope.select = function(item) {
    $scope.selected = item;
  }
});
app.directive('disableAutoClose', function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, $element) {
      $element.on('click', function($event) {
        /* prevent closing the dropdown */
        $event.stopPropagation();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
    <button id="button-template-url" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle>
    Select <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu template-url="dropdown.html">
    </ul>
  </div>

  <p ng-show="selected">Selected: {{selected.name}}</p>

  <!-- Can be a different file-->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="dropdown.html">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-template-url">
      <li role="menuitem">
        <input disable-auto-close type="text" ng-model="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in items | filter : query"><a href="#" ng-click="select(item)">{{item.name}}</a></li>
    </ul>
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried it with using Bootstrap UI and the typehead directive but couldnt make it work properly. Can you help me out with a more detailed example?

Comment: @mkoala I have added a (_two-way data-binding_) solution for how you can select and search for your data with a UI Dropdown

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I just tested it with a list of ~1k items and it works perfect. Thanks a lot!